# Sending enter in interaction mode ubuntu 13.10

Tags: command-line, apt, bash

I'm trying to make a basic script for deployment of `ocs-inventory` and I got stuck on a problem.

When I issue this command:

```
sudo apt-get install -y ocsinventory-agent
```

The interactive window appears. The only thing I need to do is press <kbd>enter</kbd>.

It's the same type of graphic prompt which you get when you are installing kerberos5.

Is there any possibility to include the "enter" in script ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically you have to preseed the answer for [debconf](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/saucy/en/man7/debconf.7.html):

```
sudo apt-get install debconf-utils
echo "ocsinventory-agent ocsinventory-agent/method select local" | sudo debconf-set-selections
sudo apt-get install -y --force-yes ocsinventory-agent
```

You can obviously change `local` by `server` for your needs.

Comment: Still not working, Getting stuck on the point where i need to choose local directory or https server

Comment: I've updated my answer as you need to prefill the debconf database to avoid the package configuration screen

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

> You can do a couple of things for avoiding this
>
> First set the variable `export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive` then you
>   can run `apt-get -y install [packagename]`, this should do exactly what
>   you want.

Source: https://serverfault.com/questions/227190/how-do-i-ask-apt-get-to-skip-any-interactive-post-install-configuration-steps

Comment: Hello, I did what you suggested but it's not working
Still getting to promt.